# Jquery: re creating googles drop down menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've used [this](http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/09/creating-the-new-top-black-bar-found-in-google-and-all-its-products/) blog post to help recreate google's drop down menu but I'm having a problem getting drop down. Can someone re fiddle and let me know where I'm going wrong? thanks a lot.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/

Comment: Don't just give us non-working code and ask us to fix it. Tell us what's not working and what you think it should do.

Comment: okay, i changed "working" to "drop down" does that help? I linked to the example and the original blog post, its googles code.. if you don't want to help no one is forcing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the jQuery function. You define it but never call it. Look at line 8-12 on the tutorial's HTML source. That was all you were missing.

You also need to set up jsFiddle to load the jquery libraries and execute your code on load. All the menus on the left do that for you.

It's working after those two changes. Check out my update here...

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/1/